Clarification on Token Access Post-Liquidity Lock in a Pool
I am examining the transactions associated with a new token on the Solana network and have come across an ambiguity.
The creator of this Token initially minted 10 million units and then added this amount to the Raydium Liquidity Pool. Following this, the creator proceeded to Lock the liquidity. However, despite claims of the liquidity being fully locked in the pool, they rapidly transferred and sold numerous tokens to various wallets. It was observed that a transaction involving multiple signatories was executed before the liquidity lock.
My question is: How is it possible for the creator to still access and transfer tokens, claimed to be locked in the liquidity pool, for selling purposes? Could this situation result from the multi-signatory transaction that was carried out prior to the locking of liquidity, and is such access typical in the development of smart contracts?
Thank you for your response and for your expert guidance.

I wanted to provide an update on my earlier query about a new token on the Solana network. It appears that after minting and adding 10 million units to the pool, the token creator actually used the pool to purchase a significant amount of the tokens.
For instance, the first buy from the pool was about 7 million tokens for 23 SOL: Transaction Link
This purchase gave the buyer around a 70% holding of the total tokens, which is more than enough to enable a potential "rug pull."
The last transaction linked seems to be related to the creation of an open-book market.
This case underscores the importance of thorough transaction analysis and understanding the flow of tokens, rather than just taking liquidity lock claims at face value.
